# How can I prevent caching of wp_redirect?

Tags: redirect, cache, wp-redirect

I am working on a multisite install where one specific site needs to have access restricted to only users who are logged in AND have a specific user meta set (key="cr_access", val="Yes").  If the user is not logged in, or that meta key is not set to "Yes", then they should be redirected to the specified url.

The redirect works properly, however it seems to be getting cached.  If a user tries to visit a page before logging in, then logs in and tries again, it is still redirecting them to the set url.  If I purge the page and object caches, then the user is able to visit the pages.  How can I prevent this from getting cached in the first place?

Here is my code:

```
function hwnycr_redirect(){

//only redirect for blog id 10, non-admin, and exclude home/login pages
if (!is_front_page() && !current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && get_current_blog_id() == 10 && get_the_ID() <> 13) {

    if(!is_user_logged_in()) {

      wp_redirect('https://example.com');
      exit();

    } else {

      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $cr_access = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'cr_access', true);

      if ($cr_access !== "Yes") {

        wp_redirect('https://example.com');
        exit();

      }

    }
  }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'hwnycr_redirect',1);
```

Comment: What kind of Caching do you use? A Plugin like W3Total Cache or WPRocket, or something like CloudFlare?

Comment: This site is on wpengine, so all I really know is that they "handle it on the server side".  I tried reaching out to their support, but they were not hugely helpful.

Comment: What about redirecting to the URL with a random parameter append?

Answer (score 3):

You should try adding `nocache_headers()` before you `wp_redirect()`. It's meant for this exact thing. [From the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/nocache_headers/):

> Set the headers to prevent caching for the different browsers.

Your scenario was mentioned and addressed in a [user contributed note](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/#comment-3973) in the WP Code Reference. That's where I picked this technique up from.

Answer (score 0):

Been banging my head against the wall on this one for months. The workaround is to set all the of redirected posts under a common slug and have WPEngine force all urls under that slug ( category ) to never cache.